# Adding pagecontroller for multiple images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

when clicked on a tableview cell it navigates to a new view to show details with content like images , it's description ,etc. For showing multiple images in page controller what can be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the images in scrollview and page Controller

```
UIScrollView *image_scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200)];
int x=0;
for (int i=0; i<image_ary.count; i++)
 {
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,screenWidth, height)];
    [image_scrollView addSubview:img];
    x=screenWidth+x;
}
[self.view addSubView image_scrollView];
UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
 pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/4, pageControlY, 160, 30);
 pageControl.numberOfPages = 5;
 pageControl.currentPage = 0;
 [self.view addSubview:pageControl];

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 float fractionalPage =scrollView.contentOffset.x / screenWidth;
        NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
        pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```